# knockout js - access variable inside object

Tags: knockout-3.0

I am trying to create a computed variable (RateDisplay) based on what the user enters(MinRate, MaxRate if VRAChecked is true, else FlatRate) that is defined as an observable. I have an object (product) as part of the viewmodel like the following:

```
var viewModel = new function () {

var self = this;
self.Id = ko.observable();

self.product = {
  Id: ko.observable(),
  Name: ko.observable(),
  VRAChecked: ko.observable(false),
  MinRate: ko.observable(),
  MaxRate: ko.observable(),
  FlatRate: ko.observable(),
  RateDisplay: ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.product.VRAChecked())
      {
        return self.product.MinRate() + "-" + self.product.MaxRate();
      }
      else
      {
        return self.product.FlatRate();
      }
  }, this),

  PercentageGoal: ko.observable()
};

  };//viewmodel ends
```

The problem is, I get this js error: "self.product is undefined" at the line

```
  if (self.product.VRAChecked())
```

I understand that, that is probably because the object is still being created.

So, how do I create the computed variable (RateDisplay)? I need it to be an element of that object (product).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating the `computed` before the other `product` properties are even created, and then, they are not defined yet.

Try to create it only after the `product` declaration, and it will work like a charm.

Take a look at the example below:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.Id = ko.observable();
  self.product = {
    Id: ko.observable(),
    Name: ko.observable(),
    VRAChecked: ko.observable(false),
    MinRate: ko.observable(),
    MaxRate: ko.observable(),
    FlatRate: ko.observable(),
    PercentageGoal: ko.observable()
  };
  
  self.product.RateDisplay = ko.computed(function() {
      if (self.product.VRAChecked()) {
        return self.product.MinRate() + "-" + this.product.MaxRate();
      } else {
        return self.product.FlatRate();
      }
    }, self)
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>Min Rate <input type="textbox" data-bind="value: product.MinRate"></label>
  <label>Max Rate <input type="textbox" data-bind="value: product.MaxRate"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Flat Rate <input type="textbox" data-bind="value: product.FlatRate"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: product.VRAChecked"> VRA Checked</label>
</div>
<div>Display: <span data-bind="text: product.RateDisplay"></span></div>
```